# How to solve exponential equation $(1-\alpha)^{\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}} = e^{-2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Good morning,

I would like to have a nice closed form expression for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies the following equality:

$$(1-\alpha)^{\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}} = e^{-2}$$

Is it even possible? I tried (the easy approach) taking logarithms, but it doesn't work... This relation appeared in a work I am doing analysing [Hoeffding's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality) and [Cantelli's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantelli%27s_inequality) inequalities in some applied math problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks to the $ISC$, a nice one would be $$\exp\left( -\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}{e} \right)\,\,\Gamma \left(\frac{23}{24}\right)$$ for an absolute error of $10^{-8}$

Comment: Looks cool! Some questions: what is ISC, how did you get it, and is the expression bigger or smaller than the actual value? @ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: Just higher. Have fun using  http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/projects/ISC/ISCmain.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My answer is for real solutions. Ask if you want complex solutions.

$$(1-\alpha)^\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}=e^{-2}$$
$$e^{\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}\ln(1-\alpha)}=e^{-2}$$
$$\frac{\alpha\ln(1-\alpha)}{1-\alpha}=-2$$
$\alpha=1-e^{-t}$:
$$-te^t+t=-2\tag{1}$$

We see, this is an algebraic equation of more than one algebraically independent monomials ($t,e^t$). The main theorem in [Ritt 1925] cannot help in these cases: We cannot read an [elementary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) inverse function over a non-discrete domain directly from the equation because we don't know how to rearrange the equation for $t$ by applying only finite numbers of [elementary functions (operations)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) we can read from the equation.

Equation (1) is an algebraic equation of both $t$ and $e^t$. According to the theorems in [Lin 1983] and [Chow 1999], such kind of equations cannot have solutions except $0$ that are [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number) or explicit elementary numbers respectively.

$$te^t=t+2$$
$$\frac{t}{t+2}e^t=1$$

We see, this equation cannot be solved in terms of [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) but in terms of Generalized Lambert W:

$$\frac{t}{t-(-2)}e^t=1$$
$$t=W\left(^{\pm 0}_{-2};1\right)$$
$$\alpha=1-e^{W\left(^{\pm 0}_{-2};1\right)}$$

So we have a [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) for $\alpha$, and the series representations of Generalized Lambert W give some hints for calculating $\alpha$.

[[Ritt 1925] Ritt, J. F.: Elementary functions and their inverses. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 27 (1925) (1) 68-90](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1925-027-01/S0002-9947-1925-1501299-9/)

[[Lin 1983] Ferng-Ching Lin: Schanuel's Conjecture Implies Ritt's Conjectures. Chin. J. Math. 11 (1983) (1) 41-50](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43836165)

[[Chow 1999] Chow, T.: What is a closed-form number. Am. Math. Monthly 106 (1999) (5) 440-448](http://timothychow.net/closedform.pdf)

[Mező 2017] Mező, I.: On the structure of the solution set of a generalized Euler-Lambert equation. J. Math. Anal. Appl. 455 (2017) (1) 538-553

[Mező/Baricz 2017] Mező, I.; Baricz, Á.: On the generalization of the Lambert W function. Transact. Amer. Math. Soc. 369 (2017) (11) 7917–7934 [(On the generalization of the Lambert W function with applications in theoretical physics. 2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999)

[[Castle 2018] Castle, P.: Taylor series for generalized Lambert W functions. 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09904)

Answer (score 1):

$\def\L{\text L}\def\F{\text F}$
There is a [Lagrange reversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem) with a different derivation than in [Castle’s paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09904) solution from @IV_’s paper:

$$(1-\alpha)^\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}=e^{-2}\implies\alpha=1-e^2+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n!}\left.\frac{d^{n-1}e^{(n-1)t}t^n}{dt^{n-1}}\right|_{t=-2}=-8.38061977\dots$$

with the [generalized Leibniz rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule):

$$\left.\frac{d^{n-1}e^{(n-1)t}t^n}{dt^{n-1}}\right|_{t=-2}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}k \left.\frac{d^k e^{(n-1)t}}{dt^k}\right|_{t=-2}\left.\frac{d^{n-1-k}t^n}{dt^{n-1-k}}\right|_{t=-2}$$

Therefore we use the [confluent hypergeometric $\,_1\F_1(a;b;x)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1F1) and the [Laguerre $\L_n(x)$ integral representation](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/LaguerreLGeneral/07/01/01/0002/):

$$\boxed{\alpha=-2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\,_1\F_1(n+1;2;2-2n)=1-e^2+\frac1\pi\int_0^{2\pi}e^{2e^{i t}+i t+2}\ln\left(1-e^{-2e^{i t}-i t-2}\left(e^{i t}+1\right)\right)dt}$$

[shown](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1-e%5E2%2BNintegrate%5B%28e%5E%282+%2B+i+t+%2B+2+e%5E%28i+t%29%29+log%281+-+e%5E%28-2+-+i+t+-+2+e%5E%28i+t%29%29+-+e%5E%28-2+%281+%2B+e%5E%28i+t%29%29%29%29%29%2F%CF%80%2C%7Bt%2C0%2C2pi%7D%5D) [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-2+sum%5B1F1%281+%2B+n%2C+2%2C+2+-+2+n%29%2C%7Bn%2C0%2C10%7D%5D). You can expand the real part of the integral for another, longer, solution.

Comment: How can one find the positive root using this method?